# Import data google spreadsheet. One column to second file. I will use gscript

Tags: google-sheets

Please help. 
I want more frequent updates so I want to use gscripts.

I need to retrieve the value of this source:

Filename: Peta Finance 
Name Sheet: Data 
Key: xxx111xxx 
Cell: B15

Target is: 
Filename: Finance 
Name Sheet: Data1 
Key: xxx222xxx 
Cell: A2

I try this code, except that they are not working:

```
function importData() {   
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //source ss
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Finance Peta"); //opens the sheet with your source data
    var values = sheet.getRange("C1").getValues(); //gets needed values
    var ts = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxx"); //target ss - paste your key
    ts.getSheetByName("Finance").getRange("B15").setValues(values);       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough I asked something similar the other day. My code, edited to match yours is as follows:

```
 function importData() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data1 Key");

   var update = 'IMPORTRANGE("XXX","Data Key!B15"); //"XXX" is the spreadsheet key of your source [Peta Finance]

   sheet.clear(); //Be careful with this. It clears the whole sheet including formatting. This part might need playing around a bit with

   sheet.getRange("A2").setValue(update);
   Utilities.sleep(245); //This just gives the set number of milliseconds before it carries out it's next process (not necessarily required if this is only action)
```

};

I then created a menu which allows me to manually refresh the data, or cell in your case. This is as follows in the same script file:

```
 function onOpen(){
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var menuItems = [
      {name: 'Import Data', functionName: 'importData'}
   ];
   spreadsheet.addMenu('Import', menuItems);
 }
```

You can then add timed triggers to set it to update, although importrange should automatically do it.

To do this click on Resources >> Current Project's Triggers >> set one up >>

Make it as follows >> Run: importData Events: Time-driven >> select the time between updates.